# Getting user input, ingredient and price and return the cheapest and most expensive one

Tags: c#

I am completely new to C# and have encountered a problem that I can't find a solution for.

The task is to write down three ingredients for a dish and then give the prices for them. Then the program is to find the cheapest and most expensive ingredients and return a message saying:

"You've selected *first ingredient* and it cost *cheapest price*"

"You've selected *second ingredient* and it cost *most expensive price*"

The code I've written below only shows the price without the related ingredient.. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thank you for your time!

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int counter = 0;
        int price = 0;
        int largest = 0;
        int lowest = 0;
        string ingredient;

        for (counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please select an ingredient");
            ingredient = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        for (counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++)
        {


            Console.WriteLine("What is the price for it?");
            price = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (counter == 0)
            {
                largest = price;
            }
            else
            {
                if (price > largest)
                    largest = price;
            }

            if (counter == 0)
            {
                lowest = price;
            }
            else
            {
                if (price < lowest)
                    lowest = price;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The most expensive ingredient costs {0} $", largest);
        Console.WriteLine("The cheapest ingredient costs {0} $", lowest);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In object-oriented programming, we see everything as an `object`. In your scenario, you have to see `ingredient` as an object that has two properties of `Name` and `Price`. In this way, understanding of business becomes really simple. I re-write your example.

try below code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq; 

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {           
        var ingredients = new List<Ingredient>();

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter count of ingredient:");
        var countOfIngredient = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        for (var i = 0; i < countOfIngredient; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");

            Console.WriteLine($"Please enter name of ingredient-{i}:");
            var name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine($"Please enter price of ingredient-{i}:");
            var price= double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            ingredients.Add(new Ingredient { Name = name, Price = price });
        }

        var cheapestIngredient = ingredients.OrderBy(i => i.Price).First();
        var mostExpensiveIngredient= ingredients.OrderByDescending(i => i.Price).First();

        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");

        Console.WriteLine($"The most expensive ingredient is {mostExpensiveIngredient.Name} with price of {mostExpensiveIngredient.Price} $");
        Console.WriteLine($"The cheapest ingredient is {cheapestIngredient.Name} with price of {cheapestIngredient.Price} $");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Ingredient
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

And completely feel free to ask questions about it. good luck